# Asynchronous http requests/multithreading when timing matters

Tags: multithreading, http, asynchronous, request

**Here's the problem I am trying to solve:**

- I have (say) 100 different sources of data that I query on a remote server
- I need to process this data as soon as possible after receiving it (the data becomes obsolete pretty fast)
- The processing times and query times are not deterministic
- I want to maximize the quantity of data that I am processing in a given period of time. The constraint is on my local program and machine only (the remote server is very efficient and not my concern).

**Here's the naive approach:**

For each data source:

- do a blocking query of the data of this source
- process the data

Obviously, this does not answer my problem, because there is a lot of downtime (during each query, the cpu is idle)

**Here's a slightly better approach:**

For each data source *s_i*:

- do a non-blocking query of the next data source (*s_i+1*)
- wait for the data of *s_i* to have been received (from the previous run of the for loop)
- check if the data is not too old (say has been received less than 5 seconds ago). If too old, do a blocking query of *s_i* again
- process the data

This method is a bit better, there is less downtime. 
I can also improve this method by doing queries up to n steps ahead rather than just the next one. I should use n low enough so that the results of the queries is not obsolete too often when I get to processing them, but high enough so that there is little down time.

This method is still not ideal though, because if the queries of *s_i+1* is received before the query of *s_i*, I will wait to have processed *s_i*

**My current solution**

I use 100 threads (1 for each data source). Each thread does the following, in an infinite while loop:

- acquire a semaphore *querySemaphore*
- launches a blocking query
- acquires a mutex (lock) *processorTimeLock*
- process the data

I think this way is better because I will not unnecessarily block waiting for a long query.

**How to improve on that?**

So that's what I've been doing. However, I have a strong feeling that this is not optimal, and that there should be a better solution to this problem that feels like a common problem.
Does anyone have ideas? Any help hugely appreciated!

Comment: I would agree that your current solution is the best one. 100 threads is not a big deal. You don't need async unless you are talking about thousands of concurrent queries.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I also need the solution to scale for thousands of threads, and the system will not allow me to spawn that many. How would you do it for, say 5,000 data sources?

Comment: in that case, you'll need asynchronous client. what language are you using? and what's the client-server protocol?

Comment: I am using python. I use 2 different client-server protocols (there are 2 remote servers): - for the first one I send post requests and receive json messages - for the second one, it is based on soap, so I use the python suds library.  I looked into gevent on python for an asynchronous http library, do you have any thoughts on it?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with python :(